# How create page scroll button like nexus5 website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I want to create scroll to section like nexus5 website https://www.google.com/nexus/5/

i.e. one button doing all. Click on one button it takes you down to different sections and when it reaches last ID it scrolls all the way up back.

JS

```
if(window.location.hash !=""){

    var scrollIdPrev = "#"+$(""+ window.location.hash +"").prev(".slide").attr("id")+"";
        var scrollIdNext = "#"+$(""+ window.location.hash +"").next(".slide").attr("id")+"";


 $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(""+window.location.hash+"").offset().top
    }, 2000,function(){
        window.location.href=scrollId;
        $(".previous").attr("data-target",scrollIdPrev);
        $(".next").attr("data-target",scrollIdNext);
    });    
}

$('.next').click(function(){

    var scrollId = "#"+$(""+ $(this).attr("data-target") +"").next(".slide").attr("id")+"";


    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(""+scrollId+"").offset().top
    }, 2000,function(){
        window.location.href=scrollId;
        $(".previous").attr("data-target",scrollId);
        $(".next").attr("data-target",window.location.hash);
    });
});

$('.previous').click(function(){

    var scrollId = "#"+$(""+ $(this).attr("data-target") +"").prev(".slide").attr("id")+"";

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(""+scrollId+"").offset().top
    }, 2000,function(){
        window.location.href=scrollId;
        $(".next").attr("data-target",scrollId);
        $(".previous").attr("data-target",window.location.hash);
    });   
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="move">
    <div class="previous" data-target="#one">UP</div>
    <div class="next" data-target="#one">DOWN</div>
</div>
<section class="slide" id="one">First</section>
<section class="slide" id="two">Second</section>
<section class="slide" id="three">Third</section>
<section class="slide" id="four">Fourth</section>
```

CSS

```
section{
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.move{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.previous, .next
{
    background: red;
    height: 20px;
    width: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhai22/s8UES/2/)

I have achieved some functionality but not all.

Comment: you are asking too much work!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the scrollIntoView() function everytime you want to scroll to the next element.

Just have an array of elements you want to go to and just save the pointer in a global variable.

```
 window.scroll=0;
 window.navigationpoints=['id1','id2','id3'];
 $('.next').click(function(){
      if(window.scroll<window.navigationpoints.length){
           document.getElementById(window.navigationpoints[window.scroll]).scrollIntoView();
           window.scroll++;
      }else {
             document.getElementById(window.navigationpoints[0]).scrollIntoView();
             window.scroll=1;
      }
 });
```